# C Thread runs only once

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to run some jobs in parallel inside a single process.
For some reason the thread I've created runs only once, please help me understand where is my mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void * print_thread (void * var)
{
    int *p_var = (int *)var;
    printf("this is a thread %d\n", ++(*p_var));

}

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    pthread_t thread1;


    if(pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, print_thread, &x)) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        usleep(100000);
    }

    return 0;
}


# gcc -o thread pthread_example.c -lpthread
# ./thread 
this is a thread 1
```

Comment: You create one thread, so it is normal it only runs once. What exactly do you expect? Did you forget the `for (x = 1; x < NBOFTHREADS; x++)` loop around `if(pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, print_thread, &x)) `?

Comment: Why do you expect it to run multiple times?

Comment: This is a new thing for me, I got it now. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of print_thread as your new threads "main". It will run from start to finish and then the thread will exit. Unless you have some kind of loop inside of print_thread, it will never persist.